# Broadcasting a multiplication across a pandas Panel

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have a pandas Panel that is long, wide, and shallow. In reality it's bigger but for ease of example, let's say it's 2x5x6:

```
panel=pd.Panel(pd.np.random.rand(2,3,6))
```

I have a Series that is the length of the shortest dimension - in this case 2:

```
series=pd.Series([0,1])
```

I want to multiply the panel by the series, by broadcasting the series across the two other axes.

1. Using `panel.mul` doesn't work, because that can only take `Panel`s or `DataFrame`s, I think

   `panel.mul(series) # returns None`
2. Using `panel.apply(lambda x: x.mul(series), axis=0)` works, but seems to do the calculation across every combination of series, in this case 3x6=18, but in reality >1m series, and so is extremely slow.
3. Using `pd.np.multiply` seems to require a very awkward construction:

   `pd.np.multiply(panel, pd.np.asarray(series)[:, pd.np.newaxis, pd.np.newaxis])`

Is there an easier way?

Comment: i think the numpy option is ok, you can use `series.values` instead of `np.asarray(series)` for a more idiomatic (imo) look.

Comment: Update: Panel is deprecated and xarray is much much better

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's anything wrong conceptually with your last way of doing it (and I can't think of an easier way). A more idiomatic way to write it would be

```
import numpy as np
panel.values * (series.values[:,np.newaxis,np.newaxis])
```

using `values` to return the underlying numpy arrays of the pandas objects.